# Stretching images in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a bar chart whose bars responds to data and change size depending on the data received. The bars are custom `UIViews` that contain a `UIImageView` that stretches accordingly. The image views have a vertical colour gradient that I'm looking to maintain at any size. I've been using `resizableImageWithCapInsets:` and it works great, however when the frame gets smaller than the image asset it squishes the entire image. I was hoping it would squish the stretchable parts first.

Slicing doesn't work because it ruins the gradient.

Is there a way to set the part of the image that you want to be stretched when the frame enlarges and squished when it gets smaller (like a harmonica)?

Comment: set content mode of the image to .contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

Comment: This doesn't work. Once the frame gets smaller it will completely resize the images. I want them to shrink only in the resizable area.

Comment: Not quite clear how you are "stretching" the images... Show an example of 3 bar heights and how you *want* it to look?